# What does "disableplugins = pnat" do?

Tags: bluetooth, debian, raspberry-pi2

https://youtu.be/GSMThZINNsc

At about about ~8:47 in the above video, the author shows `disableplugins = pnat` added to his `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf`, but I am unclear why he added it.

What does this configuration setting do?

Comment: As this is unrelated to programming, you should migrate that question from [so] to a more proper forum like [su] or [Raspberry Pi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1):

Judging by what the video's author explains and a [corroborating blog post](http://blog.davidvassallo.me/2014/05/11/android-linux-raspberry-pi-bluetooth-communication/), `disableplugins = pnat` disables the pnat plugin to avoid problems using the Raspberry Pi Bluetooth stack:

> There are plenty of guides in the internet on how to get bluetooth
>   working, but the only method that worked consistently for me is the
>   following:
>
> 1. Disable bluetooth pnat support as there seems to be a bug which stops proper operation with pnat enabled. Full details can be found
>      here: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=690749

Looking at the Debian bug's details, it explains that the pnat plugin "breaks any application that tries to run an RFCOMM server".

Comment: The bugs should be fixed in 2013